# Can we use analysis of variance to replace of t test?

Tags: statistics, anova

I know that we will get the same results whether use analysis of variance(ANOVA) or t tests when we are comparing the mean between two groups.
And this two methods have same assumption: normality and variance homogeneity.
Here is my question: Can we use ANOVA to replace of t tests? Anywhere we can use t tests correctly, we use ANOVA to instead of it. It's that right, why not?

Comment: Someone told me there are pairwise t test and single sample t test, which can not be replace by ANOVA, I have to admit it. But how about two independent samples？ Could somebody please help me?